# Laravel accessing collection data in blade without loop (key, value)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have data stored in columns meta_key and meta_value.

Is it possible to assign the meta_value to the meta_key so it can be access like the following?

```
{{ $responsedata->q1 }}
```

Controller:

```
  $getProjectLeads = RequestProjectLeads::where('r_id', '=', $rid)->get();
  $getRequestData = RequestData::where('r_id', '=', $rid)->get();
  $requestData = $getRequestData->toArray();
  return view('requests.home')->with('responsedata', $requestData);
```

Array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "r_id" => 15
    "meta_key" => "q1"
    "meta_value" => "zippyzoo"
    "created_at" => "2017-12-13 22:34:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-13 22:34:44"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "r_id" => 15
    "meta_key" => "q2"
    "meta_value" => "asdf"
    "created_at" => "2017-12-13 22:34:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-13 22:34:19"
  ]
]
```

Comment: without going into a foreach you can try to convert the getRequestData  into an array by adding ->toArray() at the end of the query
RequestData::where('r_id', '=', $rid)->get()->toArray();

or leave the querey the same and just convert the results into a array
$data = getRequestData ->toArray();

Comment: That kicks it out to a simpler, but similar array `array:1 [▼0 => array:6 [▼"id" => 1 "r_id" => 15 "meta_key" => "q1" "meta_value" => "test"...` Does this help me access within the blade as I'm looking to do?

Comment: The issue is my lack of understanding array access. It might not be possible to display a meta_value where meta_key = q1? I'm trying to avoid `{{ $responsedata->get(0)->meta_value }}` and just using the meta_key value as locator

Comment: You're not going to avoid some kind of convention like that, or like this: `$responseData->first(function($obj) { return $obj->meta_key == "qa"; });` The problem is that you can't use an array accessor because you don't care about the index, but you care about the value. This complicates things as you need a function to walk the array and return the nested array based on a given value. There's no array accessor for that.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've updated my question to better reflect desired outcome for blade handling and you've might have answered it already, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an Example:

**In your Controller:**

```
//...........
//...........
private $data;
public function Users()
{
     $this->data['page_title'] = "Users";
     $this->data['my_custom_data'] = "Users list bla bla"
     $this->data['users'] = User::where(....)->with(...)->get();
     return view('admin.users',['data'=>$this->data]); //view blade and data
 }
//........
```

**In your View:** (Examples to print or access data passed from above controller)

```
{{$data['page_title']}}

{{$data['users']}}
.....
foreach($data['users'] as $user){
    echo $user->email;
    echo $user->name;
}
{{$data['my_custom_data']}}
{{$data['users'][0]->name}}
```

Comment: Thanks -- what helped me here was `{{$data['users'][0]->name}}` Although, per @Ohgodwhy's comment, there was no avoiding this. But this was the blade help I was looking for